# MS SQL - JOIN show months that doesn't have data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a new problem with **SQL JOINS**.

Here is my scenario.

I have  a report, where I need to show sales performance for a specific customer.
The report shows the sales performance per month.

Please look at my result set:

[image: AFP035]

This is the sales report for customer AFP035. As you can see there are months that are not showing. I am required to include those months that doesn't have data(NULL).

Here what I have tried. I created a month table where I maintained the months.

[image: table months]

And then I did a **LEFT JOIN**. Seems strange because it doesn't show the desired result. From what I understand **LEFT JOIN** should show the NULL values. And I am wrong.

Please see my query:

```
select  CustNm as company,
        Cust as customer,
        Cust as custCode,
        Mon,
        case
        when Mon = 1 THEN 'January'
        when Mon = 2 THEN 'February'
        when Mon = 3 THEN 'March'
        when Mon = 4 THEN 'April'
        when Mon = 5 THEN 'May'
        when Mon = 6 THEN 'June'
        when Mon = 7 THEN 'July'
        when Mon = 8 THEN 'August'
        when Mon = 9 THEN 'September'
        when Mon = 10 THEN 'October'
        when Mon = 11 THEN 'November'
        when Mon = 12 THEN 'December'
        end as 'month',
        Yr as 'year',
        Mon as monthCheck,

        case
        when NetSales IS NULL THEN 0
        else NetSales
        end as netSales,

        case
        when PrvYrSales IS NULL THEN 0
        else PrvYrSales
        end as prevYearSales,

        case
        when SalesGrwth IS NULL THEN 0
        else SalesGrwth * 100
        end as salesGrowth,

        case
        when YrBfrLst IS NULL THEN 0
        else YrBfrLst
        end as yearBeforeLast,

        case
        when BfrLstGrwth IS NULL THEN 0
        else BfrLstGrwth * 100
        end as yearBeforeLastGrowth

from    BigEMasterData.dbo.monthtmp as a

        left outer join BigESales.dbo.tbl_ReportCOMPANYperCust as b
        on b.Mon = a.monthNo
        or b.Mon is null
```

The result is the screenshot above.

Would you help me with  this or at least enlighten me why I am not getting the desired result?

Thank you so much. Any  suggestion would be highly appreciated.

**EDIT: SOLVED: with Yogesh's help Thankyou.**

```html
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT * FROM tbl_ReportCOMPANYperCust r 
    WHERE Cust = 'AFP035'
 and Yr = 2016
)

SELECT 
       r.CustNm as company, r.Cust as customer, r.Cust as custCode, 
       a.monthNo, a.monthName, r.Yr as Year, 
       COALESCE(NetSales, 0) as netSales, 
       COALESCE(PrvYrSales, 0) as prevYearSales, 
       COALESCE(SalesGrwth*100, 0) as salesGrowth, 
       COALESCE(YrBfrLst, 0) as yearBeforeLast, 
       COALESCE(BfrLstGrwth*100, 0) as yearBeforeLastGrowth  
FROM BigEMasterData.dbo.monthtmp a
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE r on r.Mon = a.monthNo
```

Here is the result. :
[image]

Comment: Your `Calendar` table should be first table not second .

Comment: Hi @YogeshSharma, wait I would try it, Thanks for pointing that out. But still it is not working, it still show the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me correct your query, in order to get the all months then your `calendar` table should first table

```
SELECT 
       r.CustNm as company, r.Cust as customer, r.Cust as custCode, 
       a.monthNo, a.MontName, r.Yr as Year, 
       COALESCE(NetSales, 0) as netSales, 
       COALESCE(PrvYrSales, 0) as prevYearSales, 
       COALESCE(SalesGrwth*100, 0) as salesGrowth, 
       COALESCE(YrBfrLst, 0) as yearBeforeLast, 
       COALESCE(BfrLstGrwth*100, 0) as yearBeforeLastGrowth  
FROM monthtmp a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_ReportCOMPANYperCust r on r.Mon = a.monthNo
```

Use `ANSI` SQL Standard `COALESCE()` function to check `NULL` values

In order to get all months name use `CTE` or `Subquery` which could hold the filtered records

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT * FROM tbl_ReportCOMPANYperCust r 
    WHERE Cust = 'AFP035'
    and Yr = 2016
)

SELECT 
       COLAESCE(r.CustNm, LAG(r.CustNm) OVER (ORDER BY a.monthNo)) as company, 
       COLAESCE(r.Cust, LAG(r.Cust) OVER (ORDER BY a.monthNo)) as customer, 
       COLAESCE(r.Cust, LAG(r.Cust) OVER (ORDER BY a.monthNo)) as custCode, 
       a.monthNo, a.monthName, r.Yr as Year, 
       COALESCE(NetSales, 0) as netSales, 
       COALESCE(PrvYrSales, 0) as prevYearSales, 
       COALESCE(SalesGrwth*100, 0) as salesGrowth, 
       COALESCE(YrBfrLst, 0) as yearBeforeLast, 
       COALESCE(BfrLstGrwth*100, 0) as yearBeforeLastGrowth  
FROM BigEMasterData.dbo.monthtmp a
LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE r on r.Mon = a.monthNo
```

Comment: Hi Yogesh, that is so kind. But I have applied your query still it doesn;t show the missing months. I will  edit the question. Kindly see it. I added a where clause, does it change the result? Thankyou!

Comment: @danangeloalcanar.. yes filter cause the problem. use `cte` to get filtered record and then do the `join` with `calendar` table.

Comment: wow, your code works perfectly! I would read more about WITH CTE, it is a new concept to me. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Hi, @Yogesh, just a last question, as you can see in the last posted picture, there are null customerCode, how can I use the AFP035 as value if it is null? I retrieve it in a program and it says undefined index since custcode is null. Thankyou,

Comment: @danangeloalcanar..  you want `LAG()` ??

Answer (score 1):

You would appear to want:

```
SELECT c.company, c.customer, c.custCode, 
       m.monthNo, m.monthName, c.Year, 
       COALESCE(r.NetSales, 0) as netSales,
       COALESCE(r.PrvYrSales, 0) as prevYearSales, 
       COALESCE(r.SalesGrwth*100, 0) as salesGrowth,
       COALESCE(r.YrBfrLst, 0) as yearBeforeLast, 
       COALESCE(r.BfrLstGrwth*100, 0) as yearBeforeLastGrowth  
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT r.CustNm as company, r.Cust as customer, r.Cust as custCode, r.Yr as Year
      FROM tbl_ReportCOMPANYperCust
      WHERE c.Cust = 'AFP035'
     ) c CROSS JOIN
     BigEMasterData.dbo.monthtmp m LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     tbl_ReportCOMPANYperCust r 
     ON r.Mon = m.monthNo AND r.Cust = c.customer
ORDER BY m.monthNo;
```

Notice the `CROSS JOIN`.  This brings in the initial columns, so you have them even for months that do not match the data.